# How to get execution time of a piece of code in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, benchmarking, execution-time

I'm trying to benchmark a piece of code. It is based on this code [here](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/hash_append/blob/master/test.cpp) with the interesting part basically looking like this:

```
    auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    ...
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << secs(t1-t0).count() << " s\n";
```

The problem is that I am on a shared machine, and this is giving me wall time, so my results are not giving me anything consistent. What I really need is some sort of stopwatch tool that will allow me get just the time in which my code is running, rather than the wall time. What options are there? I'm on a Linux machine if it comes to system specific calls, but I'd rather keep this code portable if possible.

I've looked at other questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697995/get-time-of-execution-piece-of-code) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497630/how-to-measure-the-time-that-a-piece-of-code-takes-to-execute) but they all seem to offer wall time solutions.

Comment: Have you considered isolating the code in `main`, compiling, and running it via [`time`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(Unix))? (Not the best for measuring small pieces of code, but since you're using seconds, I assume this should be good enough)

Comment: I could do that as a last resort, however I'm running a ton of tests with a ton of configuration, and if I have to keep copying into main, this testing will take a lot longer and will be a lot less pleasant

Comment: When you say "time", do you mean CPU time?  If you were to exclude all other process's use of the CPU, would you want the time to include i/o?

Comment: There is no I/O time in this particular case. Its just small snippets of code that are testing the behavior of an unordered map with different algorithms and different input.

Comment: I was expecting to see some mention of gprof and gcc flags to make it work. Why not use a profiler for this? See questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072058/gprof-specific-function-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If available on your OS you can use the [times API](http://linux.die.net/man/2/times) to get similar results as the built in `time` command.

```
#include <sys/times.h>
...
struct tms  start, end;
times(&start);
//Do command
times(&end);
clock_t usr_time = end->tms_utime - start->tms_utime;
clock_t sys_time = end->tms_stime - start->tms_stime;
```

To be 100% complete you should check that the result of times is not equal to `-1` and check the `errno` code otherwise.

Comment: There is a typo in the answer. `start` and `end` are not pointers so the calculations should be `clock_t usr_time = end.tms_utime - start.tms_utime;` and `clock_t sys_time = end.tms_stime - start.tms_stime;`

Comment: Also, the units returned by `times()` is the number of elapsed ticks as per `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. So to get the number of seconds of elapsed time do `(double) usr_time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC` (I think).

Comment: Kilian please take the time to correct the above typo.

Answer (score 2):

For Linux

```
  #include <time.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  double  theseSecs = 0.0;
  double  startSecs = 0.0;
  double  secs;
  double  CPUsecs = 0.0;
  double  CPUutilisation = 0.0;
  double  answer = 0;
  clock_t starts;

  void start_CPU_time()
  {      
      starts = clock();;
      return;
  }

  void end_CPU_time()
  {
      CPUsecs = (double)(clock() - starts)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
      return;
  }    

  struct timespec tp1;
  void getSecs()
  {
     clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp1);
     theseSecs =  tp1.tv_sec + tp1.tv_nsec / 1e9;           
     return;
  }

  void start_time()
  {
      getSecs();
      startSecs = theseSecs;
      return;
  }

  void end_time()
  {
      getSecs();
      secs    = theseSecs - startSecs;
      return;
  }    

  void calculate()
  {
      int i, j;
      for (i=1; i<100001; i++)
      {
          for (j=1; j<10001; j++)
          {
              answer = answer + (float)i / 100000000.0;
          }
      }
  }

 void main()
 {
     start_time();
     start_CPU_time();
     calculate();
     end_time();
     end_CPU_time();
     CPUutilisation = CPUsecs /  secs * 100.0;
     printf("\n Answer %10.1f, Elapsed Time %7.4f, CPU Time %7.4f, CPU Ut %3.0f%\n",
              answer, secs, CPUsecs, CPUutilisation);  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, as the comment under your question mentioned, you should isolate the piece of code you are trying to measure inside `main` and just use the unix `time` command line tool, which reports `user` and `system` time.

If you are unable to do that, consider looking at the [source code](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/time) for `time` and potentially using the same technique to benchmark your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `clock_gettime()` with the following clocks `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` or `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID`. They give amount of CPU time consumed by a process/thread.

```
CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID
  High-resolution per-process timer from the CPU.
CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID
  Thread-specific CPU-time clock.
```

Reference:

- http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime
- [Understanding the different clocks of clock_gettime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506952/understanding-the-different-clocks-of-clock-gettime)
- http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/22/profiling-code-using-clock_gettime/

I think the advice that gives `merlin2011` is infeasible in many cases since isolating might take lots of efforts while adding two lines of code with `clock_gettime()` is quite practical. You even can wrap calls to `clock_gettime()` in a class.